# How can I customise a CS Cockpit dialog?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to add a checkbox to the refund dialog. In particular, the CS agent needs to be able to determine whether funds are returned to the user via our payment gateway or whether they're stored against the customer account as a credit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

U can extend ReturnReauestCareteWidgetRenderer in your own cockpit extension and you can add the below code for adding an extra check box.

Checkbox backOrderedInput = createSearchCheckboxField(widget, row7, "ourpaymentgtway", checked, null);